# Schedule guest account logoff on macOS

Tags: macos, guest-account

I have a macOS system at work that's used by others in the morning before I come in. The guest account is sufficient for their uses, however it's almost always left logged in and I'd like to streamline things as much as possible.

Is there any way to schedule a guest account logout on macOS? There's no option to logoff after a period of inactivity with the guest account.

I would think it's possible to crontab a script to run at the appropriate time to logout of the account and bypass the prompt warning that the session files will be lost, but this exceeds my current knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I put this in a script and added that script to the root crontab:

```
launchctl bootout user/$(id -u Guest)
```

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @GrahamMiln Yes, it seems to work fine.